# Sort part of javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, string, sorting

I have a javascript object as below. I have to sort data under AddressTotal only checking in below sequence.
1. if any element has "Prime":true then put it at first under AddressTotal. 
2. If no "Prime":true , then sort descending order on "Createdate".

Please note it's fine about "Createdate" format as I can handle that.

```
var x = {
    "accts": [{
            "Id": "Acc1",
            "Person": true,
            "Name": "Hello Roy",
            "ExternalID": "123456",
            "AddressTotal": [{
                    "Account": "Acc1",
                    "Id": "Ad3",
                    "Name": "1 camac Street",
                    "City": "Chennai",
                    "State": "KN",
                    "Zip": "23451",
                    "AddType": "office",
                    "Prime": false,
                    "RecTypeId": "R3",
                    "Createdate": "5th Feb 2018"
                }, {
                    "Account_vod__c": "Acc2",
                    "Id": "Ad2",
                    "Name": "1 strand Road",
                    "City": "Mumbai",
                    "State": "JK",
                    "Zip": "12345",
                    "AddType": "College",
                    "Prime": false,
                    "RecTypeId": "R2",
                    "Createdate": "2nd Feb 2018"
                }, {
                    "Account": "Acc1",
                    "Id": "Ad1",
                    "Name": "1 Park Street",
                    "City": "Bangalore",
                    "State": "TN",
                    "Zip": "74324",
                    "AddType": "School",
                    "Prime": true,
                    "RecTypeId": "R1",
                    "Createdate": "1st Feb 2018"
                }
            ],
            "Rectype": {
                "Name": "ABC",
                "Id": "Id1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "hasAccess": ["A1"]
}
```

Can someone please suggest me a wayout?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard [sorting problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Start with a test for prime on both elements and end with a comparison of the `Date` value of the created date.

You cannot compare `Createdate` directly as this would result in an alphabetical comparison of two string, not the mathematical comparison of timestamps.

```js
var x = {
  "accts": [{
    "Id": "Acc1",
    "Person": true,
    "Name": "Hello Roy",
    "ExternalID": "123456",
    "AddressTotal": [{
      "Account": "Acc1",
      "Id": "Ad3",
      "Name": "1 camac Street",
      "City": "Chennai",
      "State": "KN",
      "Zip": "23451",
      "AddType": "office",
      "Prime": false,
      "RecTypeId": "R3",
      "Createdate": "5th Feb 2018"
    }, {
      "Account_vod__c": "Acc2",
      "Id": "Ad2",
      "Name": "1 strand Road",
      "City": "Mumbai",
      "State": "JK",
      "Zip": "12345",
      "AddType": "College",
      "Prime": false,
      "RecTypeId": "R2",
      "Createdate": "2nd Feb 2018"
    }, {
      "Account": "Acc1",
      "Id": "Ad1",
      "Name": "1 Park Street",
      "City": "Bangalore",
      "State": "TN",
      "Zip": "74324",
      "AddType": "School",
      "Prime": true,
      "RecTypeId": "R1",
      "Createdate": "1st Feb 2018"
    }],
    "Rectype": {
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Id": "Id1"
    }
  }],
  "hasAccess": ["A1"]
};
//TEST
var arr = x.accts[0].AddressTotal.sort(function sorter(a, b) {
  if (a.Prime) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b.Prime) {
    return 1;
  }
  return new Date(a.Createdate).getTime() - new Date(b.Createdate).getTime();
});
console.log(arr);
```

By the way, is there any reason `accts` is an array and not just an object?